# Laravel convert JSON record to Class instance

Tags: php, laravel

I have a transaction record that contains a `JSON` column containing a `Client` record.

```
$t->client

{'id': 12, 'name': 'John'....}
```

I have a `Client` class

How do I instantiate a new Client class and assign the `$t->client` `JSON` values to it?

```
$billedClient = new Client;
$billedClient = collect($t->client);
```

**UPDATE:** the field contains data stored as `JSON` but in the `Transaction` class it is cast as JSON, so Laravel is converting it to `Array` by the time is it accessed in the code.

**UPDATE 2:** I have changed my code based on @mega6382's suggestion below but it fails.

```
$data = $transaction->client;
$client = new \App\Models\Client();
$client->set($data);
```

This returns an error in `Model.php` of `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

**UPDATE 3:** Solution was as suggested below without the `json_encode`.

```
$clientCollection = Client::hydrate([$t->client]);
$client = $clientCollection->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more Laravelesque way to go about it:

```
$clientCollection = Client::hydrate([json_decode($t->client, true)]);
$client = $clientCollection->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a setter in `Client` class, like this:

```
class Client {
    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can decode the json using `json_decode` and convert its object to `client` like this:

```
$data = json_decode($t->client, true);
$client = new Client();
$client->set($data);
```

Comment: Hi @mega6382. Thanks for the suggestion. See my update above, Laravel is returning `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`